# Is there an idiomatic way to concatenate paths?

Tags: c, path, idioms

So I've been looking through SO and couldn't find a clear answer.

Is there a *conventional* or *idiomatic* way to concatenate two strings which represent paths? Or is the plain `strncat`, working with bare `\` or `/` character literals the only option?

A cross platform (which works at least on Windows and Linux) would be ideal. Otherwise, a way per platform would be helpful as well.

Comment: With some limitations Windows handles forward-slashes `/` as separator. Have done it since the DOS days. But for true platform-independence you have to make special cases for all targeted platforms (which for the vast majority of people will be only Windows and POSIX (e.g. Linux and macOS) these days).

Comment: You can also use `sprintf` to generate a path name from its parts. In this case, you retain the original base part, instead of losing it by concatenation. For example, if you are exploring sub-folders, you'll want to keep the base path, for the next folder iteration.